# php query taking too much time to complete report

Tags: php, mysql

hello friend i am generating a report, first i am getting material code like this

```
$sql_srh="select Material_code,  Mat_type , Material_Desc , UOM from (
select Material_code, Mat_type , Material_Desc , UOM from opening_data where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 
'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFAB' , 'YSVM' , 'YSNV' ) and datee < '".$frm."' and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' ) union all
select Material_code, Mat_type , Material_Desc , UOM from material_data where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 
'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFAB' , 'YSVM' , 'YSNV')  and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' )
) x group by Material_code";
```

then i am using above result (material code) i am trying to generate a report, i have added code below to generate report from two tables.

```
$res = $conn->query($sql_srh);

while($res_row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

 $res_open=$conn->query("Select Sum(qty) open_blnc From (
select  qty from opening_data where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."'   and datee < '".$frm."' and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' )
Union all
select  qty from material_data where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."'   and Posting_date < '".$frm."' and 
Debit_Credit ='S' and Move_type in ('101' , '511' , '315'  , '309' , '262' , '202' , '123' , '544' , 
'334' , '552'  , '310'  , '314') and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' )
Union all
select qty from material_data where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and Posting_date < '".$frm."' and 
Debit_Credit ='H' and  Move_type in ('102' , '512' , '316' , '310' , '261' , '201' , '122' , '543' , 
'333' , '551'  , '309'  , '313') and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' )

)x");

$row_open = $res_open->fetch_assoc();


$res_in=$conn->query("select  sum(qty) as in_qty from ( 
select qty from material_data where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and Posting_date >= '".$frm."' and 
Posting_date <= '".$tdt."' and Debit_Credit ='S' and Move_type in ('101' , '511' , '315' , '309') and 
(location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' )
Union all
select qty from material_data where  Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and Posting_date >= '".$frm."' and 
Posting_date <= '".$tdt."' and Debit_Credit ='H' and Move_type in ('102' , '512' , '316'  , '310') 
and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' ) )x");

$row_in = $res_in->fetch_assoc();


$sql_out="select sum(qty) as out_qty from (
select qty from material_data where  Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and Posting_date >= '".$frm."' and 
Posting_date <= '".$tdt."' and Debit_Credit ='H' and Move_type in ('261' , '201' , '122' , '543' , 
'333' , '551' , '309' , '313') and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' )
Union All
select qty from material_data where  Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' 
, 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and Posting_date >= '".$frm."' and 
Posting_date <= '".$tdt."' and Debit_Credit ='S' and Move_type in ('262' , '202' , '123' , '544' , 
'334' , '552' , '310' , '314') and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' ))x";
$res_out = $conn->query($sql_out);
$row_out = $res_out->fetch_assoc();

$sql_adj ="Select Sum(adj) as adj_qty , Sum(opname) as opnam_qty from ( select adj , opname  from 
tbl_adj_opname where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 'YSFB' , 'YSVM' , 'YSNV') and 
Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and datee >= '".$frm."' and datee <= '".$tdt."' and 
(location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' ) and Debit_Credit = 'S'
Union All
select adj , opname  from tbl_adj_opname where Mat_type in ('YACC' , 'YFAB' , 'YLFB' , 'YLAC' , 
'YSFB' , 'YSVM' , 'YSNV') and Material_code = '".$res_row['Material_code']."' and datee >= '".$frm."' 
and datee <= '".$tdt."' and (location like 'J%' or location like 'L%' ) and Debit_Credit = 'H'
)x";

$res_adj = $conn->query($sql_adj);
$row_adj = $res_adj->fetch_assoc();
```

this is working fine , my issue is it is taking hours to generate report , i have 200000 rows in table.
if i comment above code (means open balance, in quantity and out quantity ) and run only first code (where i am getting material code) its done within seconds , but when i try to generate comelete report its taking hours .

where Mat_type and Move_Type is Fixed.

result will be like:
    ?>

```
<td class="sn"><?php echo $i;?></td>
<td><?php  echo $res_row['Material_code'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $res_row['Material_Desc'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $res_row['UOM'];?></td>
<td class="lft"><?php echo $open ;?></td>
<td class="lft"><?php echo abs($row_in['in_qty']);?></td>
<td class="lft"><?php echo $outqty= ($row_out['out_qty'])*(-1);?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_adj['adj_qty'];?></td>
<td class="lft"><?php  $balance = (($open+(abs($row_in['in_qty'])))- 
(abs($outqty)))+($row_adj['adj_qty']);
echo round($balance,3);
?></td>
<td class="lft"><?php /*echo $opnam = ($open)+($row_in['in_qty'])- 
(abs($outqty));*/  $opnam = $row_adj['opnam_qty'];?></td>
<td class="lft"><?php  $diff = ($balance)-($opnam);  echo round($diff,3); ?> 
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

[find table with testing data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yFwISkRf7ZrJXPuYLRZOwGoahE0alMTc/view?usp=sharing)
anyone please help me.

Comment: use Joins instead of UNION ALL to create reports with matching records.

Comment: include `SHOW CREATE TABLE material_data` (and for `tbl_adj_opname`). what  does `$location` expand to. Is the `Mat_type` list fixed? Are the `Debit_Credit` and `Move_type` always coupled this way? Edit question as required to answer these. Welcome to SO.

Comment: updated code as required like location and also added tables

Comment: You probably want to chuck an [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) or two into those tables, too

Answer (score 0):

USE Inner Join

ex:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Comment: can you please create open_blnc query with join because trouble to apply condition to sum quantity

Comment: i dont think applying join will execute it faster because it will expand query insted of reduce